# Dependency packaged as rar but need jar

Tags: maven, rar, xadisk

The XADisk library deployed on Maven Central packaged as 'rar' instead of 'jar'. But i just need the jar (and possibly source) for the project i'm working on. I was wondering what the best (maven style) way is to deal with this dependency.

The jar files are available on Central but not specified in the pom thus type="jar" doesnt work

the pom is here: https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/net/java/xadisk/xadisk/1.2.2/xadisk-1.2.2.pom

and the jars can be found here: https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/net/java/xadisk/xadisk/1.2.2/xadisk-1.2.2.pom

Answer (score 0):

I can't reproduce your issue, maybe they changed something in the repo?

If I add the following dependency to my project:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.java.xadisk</groupId>
        <artifactId>xadisk</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

then the JAR file gets packaged into my project.

By the way, if no "type" is specified (for the dependency), maven uses JAR as default.

Comment: i ended up not (yet) using XaDisk  so i'm not sure, but your experience indicates they likely changed it.